# Hobbyist electronics in cars

Tags: united-states, european-union, traffic

In order to place a professional electronics product inside a car or other vehicle moving in traffic, it has to be put through mandatory *type approval*, a test carried out by a neutral 3rd party test house which checks if your product conforms to elector-magnetic compatibility (EMC) requirements. The car (part) manufacturer would get a test report as proof of compliance. This is regulated pretty well world-wide by something called "UN ECE R10", a UN directive which is in turn widely adopted by many countries around the world (but apparently not by the USA).

Now since I work in electronics and is a regular user of for example electronics.stackexchange.com, I often encounter questions where someone is asking how to go about to place "hobbyist" electronics boards (Arduino, Rasp Pi etc) in cars or other vehicles. These are clearly not type approved and in addition are quite unlikely to fulfill the somewhat tough EMC requirements laid out by ECE R10 technical standards, since these are tougher than regular requirements on commercial electronics. And so these hobbyist projects always come with a risk of affecting other parts on the car, even if the hobbyist board itself isn't directly involved with a safety-critical function.

I would imagine that the situation is similar to someone modifying a vehicle to put their own home-made brakes in it. If these fail, then regular vehicle inspection would easily recognize this and require that you (the owner of the car) fix it. Except for electronics, the vehicle inspection or the police won't be able to tell the cause on-site - suppose the hobbyist board disrupts the ABS electronic brake system for example. They can tell that the brakes aren't working/failed but not why.

I am wondering what the legal consequences are for putting hobbyist boards in a car without going through type approval. Often it is someone modding their own car or motorcycle: I'm asking for scenarios where the modification has been carried out by an individual, not by a company who has put a product on market. Suppose we narrow it down to a few scenarios - will there be legal consequences in the following situations:

- The authorities find out about the non-approved electronics "preemptively". No accident has occurred but the device poses a risk.
- There was a serious accident (death or injury) caused by failing electronics on the car, but not obviously related to the hobbyist board. Suppose the ABS brake system failed but the hobbyist board is controlling the tail lights in the other side of the car.
- There was a serious accident (death or injury) caused by failing electronics and the hobbyist board is found to be the direct cause. Suppose for example that the hobbyist board jammed critical CAN bus communication on board, so that the wheel no longer responds. And that this can be proven by recorded logs.

I'm also interested to know if there any examples of similar or even precedent cases? Mainly interested in EU and/or US. I'm aware of various famous lawsuits in the US where software or electronics have caused car accidents, but there the defendant has always been the car manufacturer and not individuals who have modded their own car.

Comment: This question is similar: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47893/is-it-illegal-anywhere-in-europe-to-modify-ones-own-personal-transport. But please note that I'm not asking about which formal procedures one should go through, but rather what the consequences will be if you don't.

Comment: Such a modification will likely void the insurance, unless the insurer is informed about it and agrees to insure the car.

Comment: @Lag Most likely indeed. That might be one aspect of it, since car traffic insurance is mandatory in many countries. But suppose that nobody finds out until the scenarios described happen?

Comment: this highly depends on what the part does. Is it just a fancy "I light up the dashboard when not driving in rainbow colors" or is it "I tune the motor to inch out half a watt more power"? Is the part "safety critical" such as breaks or is it only cosmetic, such as the radio? Is it inside the car or outside? Is it a shoddy attempt to mimic a commercial part or is it properly done in a workshop from similar materials, just not certified? All those influence legality.

Comment: @Trish The point which I tried to make in detail here is that you can't reason about electronics like that. It isn't possible to claim "it just lights up the dashboard", since any electrical device comes with radiated and conducted emissions that may disrupt other electronics on the vehicle. As for who carries out the installation, I really don't see how it matters if you haven't put the device through EMC testing.

Comment: The question is very much *where* and how you mount what - the EM emissions of a 5V arduino that only runs when the car is in park mode (power to it is controlled by a NO switch on the P column of the control) mounted far away from the actual driving critical components and in a tinfoil box are so much unable to disrupt any other device in the vehicle while mounting an EMP charged by the battery and aimed at the car computer is a whole different spiel.

Comment: @Trish If a product is only active when not moving through traffic, an exception from UN ECE R10 might be carried out, so that's not relevant here. Furthermore, for example some generic hobbyist device mounted next to safety-critical parts like the ECU or ABS module etc is probably _less_ likely to cause harmful interference than say some home-made wireless device mounted around the seats, for the intended purpose of "harmless fun" transmitting music to some speakers, while also broadcasting a high radio frequency disturbance throughout the whole car.

Comment: I guess the question is then "how much EMV can the thing generate" and "how much must the car electronics accept without being affected?" If every passenger is using their cell phone in the car, connected to the cigarette plug, there's probably more disturbance than a single Arduino could ever generate.

Comment: Please note that I'm not really asking about how to establish if something is causing interference or not - I would imagine that this would be quite an intricate procedure in many cases. Hence one of the described scenarios is: what are the consequences if it is established and proven that the hobbyist device was the cause.

Comment: In the broadest generalities, the law does care for **where** it is before it concearns with **what** it is, and then with **how** it is installed. You could have 10 shoddy break disks screwed to the floor of the trunk, but for all the law cares, that's perfectly legal - that's ballast. But mount one break disk backward or a part that is unfit for the car, it matters, as that is not how the part is to be mounted in compliance with the UNECE 10. BTW, it's UNECE, not UN ECE! Which matters: it is **not** a UN regulation, it is a regulation by the **United Nations Economic Commission for Europe**.

Comment: Why do you think that when it comes to consequences, that there is a distinction between a mechanical part or an electronic part?

Comment: @Lundin The insurance policy being void, the insurer does not pay out.

Comment: @PeterM Because the regulations are different? If you put on a custom spoiler on your car, you might need to show it the vehicle inspection, but nobody forces you to hire a mechanics consultant and book time in a wind tunnel to verify that the spoiler isn't dangerous. Mechanics is more hands-on; you can easily predict the consequences of poorly installed mechanical part. Whereas there's no way to easily predict what will happen if for example some Arduino controlling a MOSFET starts shooting voltage spikes into the chassis ground or broadcast >1W amateur radio inside the engine compartment.

Comment: I think you've got a grossly inflated sense of the importance (or risk) of electronics. It's entirely possible that a mechanical feature such as a spoiler or roof rack could interfere with the car's aerodynamics or stability at high speed and contribute to an accident. Even a fur covering on the steering wheel could come loose, get in the driver's face, and cause an accident. What will count is the degree to which the person was negligent or ignored a foreseeable risk. Lots of people modify their car radios etc without causing accidents or getting jailed, but of course there's a small risk.

Comment: @StuartF I really haven't claimed that bad electronics would be a more severe risk than tampering with mechanical parts. Just that it is much harder to foresee what consequences electronics have in a car, since they are vastly more complex than anything else in it. The average car these days has some 50 to 100 different microcontrollers sitting in numerous sub-systems. You _can't_ foresee the exact consequences even as system designer, you can only force everything to follow generic design templates (EMC, ASIL qualification, MISRA software, automotive grade temperature ranges etc etc).